# Retrieve Deezer user library

Tags: api, deezer

How can I retrieve the user's library with the Deezer API?

There are methods to retrieve user's playlists, folders, albums... but there is no method to know how it's organized in order to rebuild the library tree as it is displayed in the Deezer web site.

The only way I can think of is requesting the content of each folder but that's far from optimal. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you're right. The only is to retrieve each folder and each type of content separately (playlists, albums, artists, etc.).

Comment: No plans short/medium term for that. I take note though. Thanks!